# Mac Ports Uninstall nightmare with gem 'pg"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard

I have tried everything from source installations, homebrew, and manually restoring the pg_config file as sudo user.  I am out of ideas on this... here is what I get:

`gem install pg -v '0.12.1'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/pg-0.12.1/.gemtest`

any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: you might be having an rvm issue, just by looking at the path of the permission denied error

Answer (score 3):

Probably you ran `sudo gem install pg` to install pg, so the installed gem still has `root` permission.  Run `sudo chown -R Toran1 /Users/Toran1/.rvm` to fix up the permission first. Then you should be able to run `gem install pg`

Comment: Worked as well for me. OP should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Manual gem installations like this can be installed with sudo.

```
sudo gem install pg -v '0.12.1'
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

As per the comments below, I noticed you are using rvm. Don't use sudo when using rvm. Check the paths and make sure that you do indeed have the correct permissions set!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to not use sudo when you're using RVM? The path in the asker's question definitely points to a RVM install. Perhaps use rvmsudo instead?

Answer (score 0):

use this:
RVMSUDO gem install pg